# php, ajax and html open a web page from same site but in different div tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I use php file with my output function, ie do_header and do_body etc.

In the body function I have three div tags, div 1, div 2, div 3. div 1 holding the other two position on the left and right of the div tag 1.

I have set up some links in div 2 to open a further page from the website to collect information from user.

Rather  than open a complete new webpage I want the page to open in div 3 with div 1 and div 2 remaining the same.

I have looked to try and find if this is possible but not found anything, can someone point me in the correct direction of where i can get info on this.

The html header info is held in a php function not part of the function that provides the information for the div tags 1,2 and 3.

Comment: Please share the code of your problem https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You can use an iframe to open the page in the div. I'll write a minimal code to help you in the correct direction.

Put an iframe html inside your `div-3`:

```html
<div>
  <iframe id='div3_iframe' width="500" height="350">
<div>
```

Add an `onclick` event listener to your button/link which will add source to your iframe.

```html
<button onclick='document.getElementById("div3_iframe").src="div_3.php";' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried  `iframe`? You can check [this iframe example](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp). Especially **Iframe - Target for a Link** section of the page.